# Jsbin same url address

Tags: javascript, url, jsbin

I would like to ask is it possible to keep the same url address on JSbin? Like, I've done some things before and I want to add something now, without changing the url. Is it possible without having an account there?

Answer (score 0):

This feature securely hidden, but (that saves us from the invasion of bins)

#### my experience:

1. never (**NEVER**) ("one does not simply") to press Ctrl + S (this and your problem - prevents jsbin to be the best);
2. at the entrance to another session (in another tab, or another browser, or rebooting browser):

   - Ctrl + S (only here :) ) (but more (and better) to change something, to see a new revision)
   - Alt + Back (or browser button "Back" - return to the previous page in browser history);
   - F5 (necessary);
   - "Delete" this Bin;
   - Alt + Forth (or the browser button "Forth" to return to the
     next page browser history);
   - F5 (necessary).